# How to prove the two segments are of equal length?

Tags: geometry

I met a primary geoemtry problem below, which seems too difficult for me to find a proof:

As in the figure, $P$ is a point outside circle $O$; 
$PA$ and $PB$ are tangent lines of circle $O$; $C$ is a point on the inferior arc ${\stackrel{{\mbox{$\Large{\frown}$}}}{AB}}$ distinct from $A$ or $B$;  $OD$ and $OE$ bisect $\angle AOC$ and $\angle BOC$ respectively; $PC\bot DE$.

Prove: $\overline{CD}=\overline{CE}$;

Answers/hints in primary mathematics are expected.

[image]

Comment: "Primary mathematics" means using Euclidean geometry without trigonometric identities?

Comment: If so then it is unsolvable. I consider "primary" as "pre-college"

Comment: How do you know it's unsolvable using Euclidean geometry?

Comment: I guess so. But it is difficult to prove such a conclusion. If interested, you can disprove me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three different approaches:**

**(1)**
Problem solved by using sine theorem several times.

Applying sine theorm to $\Delta OCD$ and $\Delta OCE$:

$\dfrac{\overline{CD}}{\sin{\alpha}}=\dfrac{\overline{OC}}{\sin{\angle{ODC}}}$  and 
$\dfrac{\overline{CE}}{\sin{\beta}}=\dfrac{\overline{OC}}{\sin{\angle{OEC}}}$,

Then:

$\overline{CD}=\overline{CE}\Leftrightarrow {}\dfrac{\overline{OC}\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{\angle{ODC}}} ={}\dfrac{\overline{OC}\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\angle{OEC}}}\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{\angle{ODC}}} ={}\dfrac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\angle{OEC}}}$

Applying sine theorm to $\Delta APC$ and $\Delta BPC$:
$$\frac{\overline{PC}}{\sin{\alpha}}=\frac{\overline{PA}}{\sin\angle{ACP}},\quad \frac{\overline{PC}}{\sin{\beta}}=\frac{\overline{PB}}{\sin\angle{BCP}} \Rightarrow \dfrac{\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{\angle{ACP}}} ={}\dfrac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\angle{BCP}}}$$

So we only need to prove:
$$\frac{\sin{\angle{ODC}}}{\sin\angle{OEC}}=\frac{\sin\angle{ACP}}{\sin\angle{BCP}}$$

Since $\angle{ACP}=\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\angle{ODC}\right)+\dfrac{\pi}{2},\angle{BCP}=\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\angle{OEC}\right)+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, this proves the problem.

[image]

**(2)** using cosine theorem

[image]
Since $\overline{CD}=\overline{CE}\Leftrightarrow \overline{AD}=\overline{BE}$, problem is converted into the new one.

Easy to prove $\overline{PD}^2-\overline{AD}^2=\overline{PC}^2=\overline{PE}^2-\overline{BE}^2$ and let $\theta=\angle{PAD}=\angle{OCD}-\dfrac{\pi}{2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\angle{OCE}=\angle{PBE}$, then apply cosine theorem to $\Delta PAD$ and $\Delta PBE$ to compare the expressions of $\cos\theta$ we can obtain $\overline{AD}=\overline{BE}$.

Note the case when $C$  exactly bisects arc $AB$ is trivial.

**(3)** 
Further auxiliary conductors:

[image]

**(4)**
new solution:
[image]